# NSCombox's comboBoxSelectionDidChange value is delayed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, combobox

I have a NSAlert with a combobox in it and i need to know it's value every time it changes.

In my .h i have implemented the `NSComboBoxDelegate` protocol and `NSComboBox* comboBox`.
In my .m i have:

```
[comboBox setDelegate:self];


- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    int x = [[comboBox stringValue] intValue];
    NSLog(@"ComboBox Value Changed to --> %i", x);
}
```

But here is the problem:
the default value of the combobox is 2. if i change the value to, for example, 6 my `NSLog` displays: `ComboBox Value Changed to --> 2`
Then, when i change it's value back to 2, my `NSLog` displays: `ComboBox Value Changed to --> 6`
Any ideas about this problem? 
Thank you.

PS: i have tried other `NSComboBoxDelegate` methods but it happens the same thing as i described above.

Comment: How are you changing the value?  In code, or by user interaction?

Comment: by user interaction. my combobox is not editable, but it has 10 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to use objectValueOfSelectedItem instead of stringValue.

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    int x = [[notification.object objectValueOfSelectedItem] intValue];
    NSLog(@"ComboBox Value Changed to --> %i", x);
}
```